How to get unstoppable domain owned by wallet address?
How to get unstoppable domain owned by user wallet address?
I need to obtain all domains that user have.
Preferred language js, please tell me what tool will help me

They have some documentation for deverlopers you should take a look at it https://docs.unstoppabledomains.com/.
